# How to update jsonb field in Postgres v9.4+ using Peewee

Tags: postgresql-9.4, jsonb, peewee

I learned that in Postgres v9.4 and above, one can do partial updates to jsonb columns.

I am using Peewee on top of my Postgres database. Peewee has a support to declare a column jsonb but I cannot find an efficient way of updating the jsonb column to harness the power of partial update.

Here's what I am doing -

```
SQL = "update table_name set data = data || %s where tid = %s"
vals = (json.dumps(partial_data), tid)

db_pointer.execute_sql(SQL, vals)
```

`data` is the column name

`db_pointer` is the pointer to Postgres database using playhouse.

The above code works fine, but here I am not using Peewee to update it. It just a normal query to the database.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented on GitHub, you can instead:

```
data = {'some': 'data', 'for json field': [1, 2, 3]}
query = ModelClass.update({
    ModelClass.data: ModelClass.data.concat(data)
}).where(ModelClass.id == some_id)
query.execute()
```